# Why doesn't the minimal polynomial of a matrix change if we extend the field?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Why doesn't the minimal polynomial of a matrix change if we extend the field?
 I appreciate any help or proof.

Comment: Well, it can change: over some field it can be reducible to a product of linear factors, over other one it may not...what do you man by "change"

Comment: Well, yes.  The form of the minimal polynomial _can_ indeed change, but the minimal polynomial cannot.

Comment: Well, you can write $\;(x-i)(x+i)\;$ in $\;\Bbb C[x]\;$ , yet you can *not* write that for $\;x^2+1\in\Bbb R[x]\;$ ...imo it is more than just the polynomial's "form".

Comment: @DonAntonio: They are still the same polynomial. That's like saying $-1$ changes of value in $\mathbb{C}$ because it then becomes $i ^2$.

Comment: No, it's not the same. I'd say the correct analogy it's like saying that $\;\sqrt{-1}=i\;$ *everywhere*.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Are you claiming that $x^2 + 1 \neq (x-i)(x+i)$?

Comment: Of course I am, @nik: in $\;\Bbb R[x]\;$ they are not the same. Are you claiming they are the same in **that** polynomial ring??

Comment: @DonAntonio: yes, I am claiming they are, IF you consider $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (which IMO is legitimate).

Comment: Of course you consider it so, but in $\;\Bbb R\;$ there does not exist any element $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ and thus the polynomials $\;x\pm i\;$ doesn't exist there.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, but the polynomial $(x+i)(x-i)$ does exist there. And it is equal to $x^2+1$. This discussion is somewhat sterile, I don't really see your point.

Comment: The reduction to $\;(x-i)(x+i)\;$ cannot be done in the ring $\;\Bbb R[x]\;$ as none of the two factors belong to that ring, and you're right about this discussion. Final point now.

Comment: @DonAntonio, see earlier question at the link in my "answer"

Comment: Ah, great comments and answers there, @WillJagy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you will find such polynomial $f$ that $f(A)=0$, you have to solve a system of linear equations with elements of matrices $A,A^2,\ldots$ as coefficients. Hence the coefficients of $f$ must belong to the same field as elements of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

see [Can a matrix in $\mathbb{R}$ have a minimal polynomial that has coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/can-a-matrix-in-mathbbr-have-a-minimal-polynomial-that-has-coefficients-in)

The proof is easy if going from the rationals or reals by just adjoining $i = \sqrt {-1}.$ It gets a bit more intricate in arbitrary finite extensions, as we are not always guaranteed an automorphism of the extension field that fixes the base field and **only** the base field. Still true. I would actually like to see more detail on those three answers myself.

Comment: Let $m(x)\in F[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, and let $K$ be any field extension of $F$.  Let $f_i(x)$ be the irreducible factors of $m(x)$ in $F[x]$.  Then, despite the fact that $f_i(x)$ may factor in $K[x]$, the collective roots of its factors will be roots of $m(x)$.  This is because the Galois group $Gal(K/F)$ of $K$ over $F$ leaves $f_i(x)$ invariant (it fixes the coefficients of $f_i(x)$ since they are elements of $F$).  Since $f_i(x)$ is irreducible, $Gal(K/F)$ will transitively permute its roots.  Thus each $f_i(x)$ will appear in $m(x)$ whether $f_i(x)$ factors or not.