# How does one find a set of square matrices that commute with each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> How does one find a set of square $n \times n$ matrices that commute with each other?

It seems that there were some stuffs said about invertible and non-invertible, but not about a set of matrices that commute with each other.

Of course, there will be different possible sets, and my question is can every natural number bigger than 2 can be guaranteed to be the cardinality of such set, and if it does, how can we derive such set?

Comment: There is a trivial answer to your question: yes, as for every $k$, $\{I_n,2I_n,\ldots,kI_n\}$ is such a set. And you can get sets like that of cardinaity up to that of you underlying field. Unless I misread again.

Comment: @julien, so what is the maximum dimension?

Comment: @WillJagy Not sure I understand. The OP asks about sets and their cardinality. Not dimension. Oh, I see, your question in your answer...

Comment: @julien, yes, and you have answered that, as I read it. But I find that I do not know this other thing, and perhaps you do.

Answer (score 3):

BACKGROUND: [Given a matrix, is there always another matrix which commutes with it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it)

Start with any fixed square matrix $A,$ size $n$ by $n$ as you say. Cayley-Hamilton says that $A$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $n.$ Which means that any polynomial in $A$ can be re-written as
$$ a_0 I + a_1 A + a_2 A^2 + \cdots + a_{n-1} A^{n-1}.  $$
All such matrices commute with each other.

Someone once pointed out to me that this also applies to any real analytic function of $A,$ such as $e^A.$ I think it was Marc van Leeuwen. Anyway, that is correct. So, you get a vector space of matrices of dimension $n,$ out of the full dimension of $n^2.$ That would be my question, is $n$ the **maximum dimension** of a vector subspace of matrices, all of which commute with each other?

Note, you want $A$ to have $n$ distinct eigenvalues to get full value out of this. For example, if $A=I,$ all polynomials are just $a_0 I,$ dimension 1.

Comment: @julien, maybe, maybe not. $A^j A^k = A^k A^j.$

Comment: Actually, as you can see, I deleted my comment even before that. Sorry about that.

Comment: @julien, this way, it keeps the reader on his toes. Or her toes.

Comment: That's a good question you raise, +1.

Comment: Such a vector space of dimension $k$ generates a commutative subalgebra of dimension $\geq k$. Now it is known for [the maximum dimension of a commutative subalgebra](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29087/commutative-subalgebras-of-m-n) in $M_n(K)$ is $1+\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$. So your $k$ is not greater than that. Given the example in Robin Chapman's answer, this seems to be optimal for subspaces too.

Comment: @julien, thanks, I'll go through that. So you just get max $=n$ for $n = 2,3.$ Improves for $n \geq 4.$

Comment: The set of all diagonal matrices are commuting,and its dimension is n.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, unless some $A$ in a maximal subspace is similar to a single Jordan block, the dimension of that maximal subspace is **always greater** than $n$. Suppose $A$ has $n$ repeated eigenvalues. Then WLOG, we may assume that $A=J_1\oplus\cdots\oplus J_m$, where $m>1$ each $J_i$ is a Jordan block. So, $A$ at least commutes with those upper block triangular matrices of the form $B=(B_{ij})_{i,j=1}^m$, such that $B$ has conforming partitioning to $A$ and each $B_{ij}\ (i\le j)$ is an upper triangular (and perhaps rectangular) circulant matrix.