# I have to show $B\in F[A]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in M_n(F)$. Set $C(A)=\{X\in M_n(F) \mid XA=AX\}$. Similarly $C(B)$ is defined. If $C(A)\subseteq C(B)$, I have to show $B\in F[A]$. ($F$ is a field.)

Comment: What's definition of $F[A]$ ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497806/matrices-b-that-commute-with-every-matrix-c-commuting-with-a

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known theorem contained in Wedderburn's "Lectures on matrices", page 106.

**Theorem (Wedderburn):** If the matrix $B$ commutes with every matrix that commutes with $A$ then $B$ is a scalar polynomial of $A$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497806/matrices-b-that-commute-with-every-matrix-c-commuting-with-a) for a proof, or [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-08/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4.pdf).