# A commutes with everything that commutes with B

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, linear-transformations

Let $A,B$ be two matrices over a field. Suppose that $A$ commutes with every matrix $X$ which commutes with $B$. Show that $A$ is a polynomial in $B$.

Comment: @hardmath, I agree this is a nice problem. But if you can understand what the OP trying to say, you can edit the problem and try to improve formatting so that it is easier to read for most people. I think that will be more helpful for a person who asked the first question on this website. Thanks.

Comment: This was answered before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497806/matrices-b-that-commute-with-every-matrix-commuting-with-a/497818#497818

Comment: @user370831 there's no need to do so.  But, if you really want to delete the question, I think you'll find the button to do so next to "edit".

Comment: @user370831 if the button isn't there (I don't remember how it works for sub-100 rep users), then let me know and I can flag it for deletion.

Comment: It isn't there.

Comment: The delete button is not available for unregistered users, as is the case here.  @QingZhang:  You were quick to edit the Question, but as I anticipated the duplicate issue, I thought it a better opportunity for the new user to learn how to ask and edit their own Question.  (On many, many occasions I have edited the problem statement from a title into the body of the Question.)