# On existence and uniqueness of non-trivial solution of matrix equation $AX=XA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Now I have a matrix equation $AX-XA=0$, where $A=A^T$ is real symmetric and $X=-X^T$ is unknown and skew-symmetric. I have transformed the equation into the following,
$$(I_n\otimes S-S\otimes I_n)~\mathrm{vec}X=0$$
According to relevant theory of Sylvester equation, if $X$ is general, this doesn't admit a unique solution. But is there any non-trivial *skew-symmetric* solution? What's the dimension of solution space? Or, how to solve it?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it).

Comment: Going back to the original matrix equation, it asks which matrices $X$ commute with a given matrix $A$.  While the solutions $X$ form a subspace of matrices (of whatever size $A$ is), its unclear what you mean by asking "the dimension of null space".  Of course the equation itself is homogeneous.

Comment: @hardmath Yes. And null space here is exactly the space of solution.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks. But my field is real. And is it possible there being a unique solution when $X$ is skew-symmetric?

Comment: If by "unique solution" you mean "only the trivial solution" $X=0$, then no, that is not the case for any matrix $A$.

Comment: @hardmath Oh, sorry. I mean uniqueness of nontrivial solution.

Comment: But it's a homogeneous problem.  There's a whole vector space of solutions having positive dimension.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, up to a scalar.

Comment: If you are suggesting the dimension might be one, this would only be true if $A$ were a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @hardmath Probably not. If $A$ is a real, $X\equiv 0$ is the unique solution, hence the dimension of solution space is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be real symmetric, and thus orthogonally diagonalizable:

$$ D = QAQ^T $$

If $D$ has any two diagonal entries equal, then a nontrivial skew-symmetric $Y$ will commute with $D$.  Set $X = Q^T Y Q$ and you will have a skew-symmetric $X$ that commutes with $A$.

Without loss of generality we may assume the first two diagonal entries of $D$ are equal:

$$ D = \begin{pmatrix} rI & 0 \\ 0 & D' \end{pmatrix} $$

where block diagonal $rI$ is of dimension at least $2\times 2$.  Then take compatible block diagonal matrix:

$$ Y = \begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$Y$ will now commute with $D$ for any block $B$, and in particular if $B$ is skew-symmetric, so too will $Y$ be skew-symmetric.

The rest of the verification (that $X = Q^T Y Q$ is skew-symmetric and commutes with $A$) is routine.

Comment: Thanks, could you also give a proof?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Diagonalize $A$. Typically you'll get $X = 0$ as the solution

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "typically".  $X=0$ is always a solution, but there are nontrivial solutions as well.

Comment: @hardmath I mean that for generic $A$ (e.g., drawn randomly) you only get $X=0$.

Comment: @S.B. What if $A=I$?

Comment: @user1551 As I said for a **generic** $A$ the only answer is $X=0$. If I wanted to explain more about how the solutions look like depending on the eigenvalues of $A$, I would have given the full answer.