# Show that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix that commutes with $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with distinct eigenvalues.
And suppose $B$ commutes with $A$. Show that $B$ is diagonable;
i.e., show that $B$ is similar to a diagonal matrix.

I get that $AB=BA$ and that some diagonal matrix $D$ that is similar to $B$ is $D=SBS^{-1}$ and that $S$ is composed of the eigenvecotrs of $B$ I just don't know what to do from their.

Comment: Hint: "Simultaneously diagonalisable"

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $Ax = ax, a$ scalar, then
$$a Bx = B(ax) =
B(Ax) = BAx= ABx
$$
and you know that the subspace
$$\{y: Ay = ay\}
$$is a line...

Comment: If I wanted to be difficult, I could point out that the matrices might not be over $\Bbb C$. But the hint is sound.

Comment: @Arthur $\Bbb C$ can be replaced by any field.

Answer (score 1):

The big theorem is that, for a square matrix $A$ for which each eigenvalue occurs in only one Jordan block, all matrices that commute with $A$ can be written as polynomials in $A.$ This includes matrices with distinct eigenvalues, as each Jordan block is one by one. So
$$ B = b_0 I + b_1 A + b_2 A^2 + \cdots + b_{n-1} A^{n-1}.   $$ 
You do not need higher degree because of Cayley-Hamilton.

Oh, $A$ itself is diagonalizable because of the distinct eigenvalues. Some $P^{-1}A P = E$ diagonal. What can you say about $P^{-1}B P ?$

Note: I keep collecting equivalent conditions to the Jordan block thing, [Given a matrix, is there always another matrix which commutes with it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832)