# Symmetric matrices and commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q: Let $m, n$ be positive intergers. Let $A$ and $B$ real $n\times n$ matrices. Assume that $B$ is symmetric and positive definite. If $A$ commutes with $B^{m}$, prove that $A$ commutes with $B$.

So I don't really know where to start with this other than the decomposition theorem for symmetric positive operators, so that I can write $B$ as diagonal with positive real entries. Perhaps taking the $m^{th}$ root could be useful which we can do since $B$ has positive entries, but I'm not sure.

Many thanks!

Comment: It is enough to prove that there exists a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}\left[x\right]$ such that $B = p\left(B^m\right)$. To prove this, we can WLOG assume that $B$ is diagonal (since $B$ is diagonalizable). Now it is clear that we can set $p$ to be any polynomial which sends the $m$-th powers of the eigenvalues of $B$ to said eigenvalues. Do you know why such a polynomial exists? (You still need to use positive definiteness -- make sure that you do so, or else the proof is wrong.)

Comment: I've been trying, but no progress. Would I try to use the minimal polynomial for $B$ or $B^{m}$ somehow? Or should I be trying to just write it out from scratch?

Comment: This last step is not really a matrix problem. Do you know about Lagrange interpolation?

Comment: Reading about it now on wikipedia. So I would use Lagrange interpolation to get a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(\lambda^{m})=\lambda$, but how does positivity come into this?

Comment: Yes, that's the question :). What is the main condition for Lagrange interpolation to work?

Comment: does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it) help ?

Comment: So, what I've read about the interpolation procedure, nothing is mentioned about when it fails. I would guess some kind of problem occurs when not all of the points have the same sign, but that is as much as I can guess. Granted, perhaps I just skimmed the articles on wiki too much and need to read them in more detail. Edit: Ah, is it that if the points have different sign there are some extra roots involved which are undesirable?

Comment: As for the link provided by r9m I will read it in detail tomorrow, thanks :)

Comment: No, signs are not the issue per se. But you cannot find an interpolating polynomial if you want two different values at the same point. Why will this not happen here?

Comment: Well, if say $\lambda$ was negative and $m$ was even then $\lambda^{m}$ would be positive, hence the existence of the polynomial we want would not be guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, $B$ is symmetric and positive definite, it is Unitarily diagonalizable, that is $\exists \, U \in U_n(\mathbb{R})$, such that $U^{*}BU = D[d_1,\cdots,d_n]$ is a diagonal matrix, with $d_i > 0$, for all $i = 1(1)n$.

Denote, $U^{*}AU = W = (w_{ij})_{n \times n}$, then,

$AB^m = B^mA \implies U^{*}AU(U^{*}BU)^m = (U^{*}BU)^mU^{*}AU \implies WD^m = D^mW$

So, $d_i^mw_{ij} = w_{ij}d_j^m$ for all $i,j$

Which implies, $d_iw_{ij} = w_{ij}d_j$ for all $i,j$ (since, $d_i,d_j >0$ and $d_i^m = d_j^m \implies d_i = d_j$)

That is $WD = DW$, which in turn implies $AB = BA$.

Comment: Yeah that works. I like the answer given in the comments above as as well, using the Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps yes that is nice too ! :)