# Matrix dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is a fixed n by n matrix, and
S := {$B\in  M_n(\Bbb{C}) : AB = BA$}
is a subspace of $M_n(\Bbb{C})$.

Find a 3 by 3 matrix A such that S has dimension 5.

I figured the matrix below has dimension 3 when multiplied with B

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & i \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

So for a general matrix B, I did AB=BA, and then compared both sides and wherever the corresponding entries didn't match, I concluded them to equal zero. $$ B=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & j \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: you need to choose a,b,c,d,... so that the corresponding entries do match. you will find out that everything is zero except a,e, and j. so $S$ has dimension $3$ not $5$ as required

Comment: I need to find a matrix A such that when multiplied by B on either side it has dimension 5. The matrix A above is what I tried that gave me dimension 3, not 5. Thus, it's wrong. So the goal is to find a fixed matrix A that has dimension 5.

Comment: that is right. I gave an example of such a matrix in my answer below. First, verify that $AB=BA$

Answer (score 1):

Try the matrix

A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 &  1 & 0 \\
        0 &  0  & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
and

B=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        0 & a & 0 \\
        0 & h & j \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Comment: May I ask how you came up to this solution.

Comment: when the minimal polynomial coincides with the characteristic polynomial then a matrix $A$ commutes only with $p(A)$ where $p$ is a polynomial. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it so I looked for a matrix whose minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^2$