# Find the dimension of matrices such that $Ae_{ij} = e_{ij}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

> Find the dimension of $n$ by $n$ matrices such that $Ae_{ij} = e_{ij}A$. Where $e_{ij}$ is a matrix with $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

So $Ae_{ij}$ takes the takes $i$th column of $A$ by inserting $j-1$ columns of $0$ before it and completing matrix up to the number of columns of matrix $e$ by also inserting columns of $0$.

For example if 
$\begin{bmatrix}4&5&6\\7&8&9\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&4\\0&0&7\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

At the same time $e_{ij}A$ takes the $j$th row of $A$ and setting $0$'s else.

Comment: See the very general theorem in the answer of Pedro Tamarov [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1476643)

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't understand it but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the matrix $Ae_{ij}$ is a matrix with the $i$-th column of $A$ at the $j$-th column position of $Ae_{ij}$. Also the matrix $e_{ij}A$ is a matrix with the $j$-th row of $A$ at the $i$-th row position of $e_{ij}A$. If these two matrices be equal, then **all the elements of the $i$-th column and $j$-th row of $A$ must be zero, except that one which is common in position between them for which we have $$a_{ii}=a_{jj}$$**(recall your own example for that). Therefore the dimension is $n^2-2n+2$ when $i\ne j$ and $n^2-2n+3$ when $i=j$.

Comment: Please, can you clarify a bit how did you got the $n^2-2n+2$ and $n^2-2n+3$?

Comment: Sure. Define $B=Ae_{ij}$ and $C=e_{ij}A$. Do you agree that $$b_{kj}=a_{ki}\\c_{ik}=a_{jk}$$ and the rest are zero?

Comment: Where $k$ is what? I agree that $a_{ii} =a_{jj}$ and the rest are zero. I will just tell you my logic while I am trying to solve for the dimension. If $i \not = j$ then $e_ij$ can not be a diagonal therefore it can be in the remaining $n-1$ positions of the imaginary upper triangular matrix. Therefore the dimension should be $(n-1)^2/2$ but since we have the symmetric picture below the diagonal than multiply by $2$ and get $n^2-2n+1$. While, if $i=j$ there are just the $n$ diagonal positions so the dimension is $n$.

Comment: OK. When the others are zero (which are $2n-2$ in number) they reduce the dimension by this number and lead to $n^2-(2n-2)=n^2-2n+2$. If $i=j$, the condition $a_{ii}=a_{jj}$ is inclusive and if $i\ne j$, we have another reduction in dimension leading to $n^2-2n+1$ but note that $b_{jj}=c_{ii}$ which leads to another increment in dimension.