# Minimal polynomial and Characteristic are equal .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix:-
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\dots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 &  \dots & c_n  
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and I want to show that its characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial are same, that is to show that they have the same eigenvalue. So what do we know about the eigenvalue of matrix in this form.

Comment: You can calculate the characteristic polynomial by expanding along the the first column and using induction.

Comment: this kind of matrices are well known and they are dubbed  **Companion's Matrices**

Comment: @janmarqz thanks, its new to me this kind of matrix. I just learned something new.

Comment: also notice this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B-c1%2C-c2%2C-c3%2C-c4%7D%7D

Comment: I've collected several related conditions at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832  It turns out that merely being similar to a companion matrix is enough.