# Prove that the set of commuting matrices is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Prove that the set of real commuting matrices with the matrix $A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ is a vector space relative to standard operations on matrices. Find the dimension and a basis for that space.

Question: Is it necessary to check the subtraction for commuting matrices.

What are the steps for proving the given statement?

Comment: I suppose it means the set of real matrices $B$ such that $AB=BA$. For proving it is a vector space, it suffices to prove it is a subsapce, i.e. non-emptyness, closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to show it is a subspace of the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices.

Clearly the zero matrix commutes with $M$.

Supose $A$ and $B$ commute with $M$. then $(A+B)M=AM+BM=MA+MB=M(A+B)$.

We also have $(cA)M=c(AM)=c(MA)=M(cA)$, so the matrices that commute with $M$ contain the zero matrix and are closed under addition and scalar multiplication, therefore they form a subspace of the vector space of matrices as desired.

Comment: Indeed, it is important to note that definition of $A$ is irrelevant. The only condition is that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: The OP seems to have forgotten, but the question also asked for dimension and a basis. This can be done in an entirely elementary way (and I wish the OP had followed my suggestion), write another matrix $B$ with all entries distinct letters, compare $AB$ and $BA,$ equality gives many simple (linear) relations among the entries of $B.$ Conclusion is a case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832

Answer (score 1):

For even $n$, the matrices that commute with each other has the following block form:

\begin{bmatrix}
     aI & M \\
     0 & aI \\
    \end{bmatrix}

Each block $(0, aI, M)$ has $\frac{n}{2}\times\frac{n}{2}$ rows and columns. 
The matrix of the question is:

$A$=        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

$A$ doesn't have the block form I mentioned above, so the only matrix that can commute with it is the zero matrix.