# Jordan form - cyclic vector chains

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form

My teacher asked us to find the cyclic vector chains of a matrix. We are in the section on Jordan Normal Forms. Does anyone know what they are talking about? I can't find anything on google or in my book to read about it. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look for example at https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cyclic_vector

Comment: also look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832

Comment: https://www.mapleprimes.com/maplesoftblog/201749-Transitioning-To-Jordan-Form