# Find the matrices $X$ that commute with $A$. (Solve $XA=AX$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2\\ 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$ solve $$XA = AX.$$

Multiplying with inverses from the different sides doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: This is a small enough problem that you could just set $X = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, calculate the entries of $XA$ and $AX$, and solve the resulting system of equations.

Comment: The more general picture is given by Sylvester equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). But I don't advise you to use this sledgehammer. The advise of @JimmyK4542 is a good one.

Comment: @JeanMarie there is a way with intermediate difficulty, see my answer here or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$X = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$
Now, let's consider what conditions $X$ must satisfy such that it commutes:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
This multplies out to be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a +2c & b+2d \\ -c & -d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a & 2a-b \\c & 2c-d\end{pmatrix}$$
So, we now have 4 equations that must be satisfied.
Some of them, like $c = -c$, easily give us a conclusion (that $c = 0$).  After this, we see that $a = a$, and $-d = -d$, so these can be anything.  The only other real condition is that $b+2d = 2a-b\implies b = a-d$. So, we have that:
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}a & a-d \\ 0 & d\end{pmatrix}$$
Should work for any choice of $a$ and $d$.

Comment: Thank you, clear and concise!

Answer (score 1):

As the two (evident) eigenvalues are distinct, it follows that the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial of $A$ coincide. Therefore, the only matrices that commute with $A$ are polynomials in $A$ itself, that is
$$ sI + t A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
s + t & 2t \\
0 & s-t
\end{array}
\right)
   $$
It is not necessary to use terms $A^2$ or $A^3$ because of Cayley-Hamilton

See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it/92832#92832  for some background

Comment: I had forgotten this result which provides a very direct proof. Thanks for recalling it !